# Nginx conditional rewrite

Tags: nginx, https, dns, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect domain1.com to domain2.com based on http/https.

- So a request to http://domain1.com will go to http://domain2.com.
- Request to https://domain1.com goes to https://domain2.com

My current Nginx vhost file setup as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/xxx.key;

    server_name *.domain1.com;
    if ( $scheme = "https" ) {
        rewrite ^ https://domain2.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    rewrite ^ http://domain2.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

However visiting https://domain1.com just goes to http://domain2.com. I can't seem to detect https. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I have edited my vhost to the below but the same issue occurs.:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/xxx.key;

    server_name *.domain1.com domain1.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain2.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: BTW, `server_name *.domain1.com;` do not match `domain.com`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I want `server_name *.domain1.com domain1.com` in order to match all www and variations of domain1.com correct?

Comment: Yes. Or just `.domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `if` and `rewrite`

```
return 301 $scheme://domain2.com$request_uri;
```

Comment: I have tried the above but the same issue appears to happen, https://domain1.com redirects to http://domain2.com.

Comment: Are you sure, it's not browser cached redirect? Have you tried with curl or wget?

Comment: Yes, I have tried clearing my cache and the same behavior seems to happen.